# Change "from" address in Terminal `mail`

Tags: terminal, email, command-line

When sending mail from shell, e.g.,

`echo '123' | mail -s 'subject' name@mail.com`

The recipient gets an email from "my-local-username@my-machine-name.local", e.g., "bob@macbook.local"

How can I change this to an email address of my choosing?

Answer (score 1):

Tack an escape to the end of your mail command to pass a header to sendmail.

```
 -- -f not-bob@address.com
```

See this answer and others that use the -- terminator to tell the mail program those arguments are for the next program.

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/8483239/475228

Comment: Does not work for me, at least on 10.11.6